# Html lang attribute is not coming on page source

Tags: javascript, html, razor, accessibility

I am working on a portal site to make it accessible. It is in two languages- English and French. Its developed in Razor engine MVC. My problem is while i am viewing the page source code through right click, its lang attribute is not showing but if viewing it using f12 its lang attribute is coming properly.

I have set the code for this as

```
<input type="hidden" id="page-culture-value" value="@this.Culture" />
```

And its javascript is given as-

```
var language = $("#page-culture-value").val();
$("html").attr("lang", language);
```

Comment: Depending on the browser (and version), View Page Source may show the code as it was downloaded originally, not what was later updated via JavaScript. Is there any reason you don't just the the value in the Razor, like `<html lang="@this.Culture">`?

Comment: Can I give like this?? will it take the value?

Comment: yess...its working absolutely fine... thank you so much... :) :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: You might want to make an answer about it, as it seems to solve OP’s problem.

Comment: About source code: +1, you can use F12 (DevTools, Firebug, etc) to inspect current values of attributes. And with Firefox and good ol' WDT (Web Developer Toolbar), last item of menu has "View **Generated** source code" that will show current DOM as tags and attributes *after* JS was executed, not simply as initially sent by the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser (and version), View Page Source may show the code as it was downloaded originally, not what was later updated via JavaScript.

You may want to consider just outputting the HTML directly in the Razor code, like this:

```
<html lang="@this.Culture">
```

Comment: Hi Mike... Can you help me out in this too---  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254081/how-to-give-focus-to-dynamic-content